# My SQL if statement is not reading the value i pass it

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, stored-procedures, where-clause

Hi i am relatively new to SQL so this is probably a basic question. i am trying to pass a variable and use that variables content to determine what it runs. The variable is a `char(2)` and it can have the following possible values:

**Accepted**
 = `AP`

**All**
 = `AL`

**Declined**
 = `DE`

**Line Manager Accepted**
 = `LA`

**Admin Accepted**
 = `AA`

here is what it should do. I should input a start and an end date and then the two digit code to decide which holiday bookings i select. in the example below i am looking for a date range between the 2 holidays with any status (accepted or declined):

```
    EXEC spSearchHoliday '2013-04-01','2015-05-24','PE'
```

This returns the correct result! But if i try to run a date search between two dates with any other status it continues to return every date. in the example below i want only to return accepted holidays:

```
    EXEC spSearchHoliday '2013-04-01','2015-05-24','AP'
```

But instead it still returns every status holiday between the range.

Below is the stored procedure itself the long `holidays.startdate` and `holidays.EndDate` sections work fine its jsut the status related parts that are not working correctly.

```
    AS
BEGIN
    IF @Status = 'AL'
        BEGIN
            SELECT  StartDate,
                    EndDate,
                    Duration,
                    [Status]
            FROM    Holidays
            WHERE   Holidays.Startdate <= @Startdate AND Holidays.Enddate >= @EndDate
                    OR Holidays.Startdate >= @Startdate AND Holidays.Enddate <= @EndDate
                    OR Holidays.Startdate <= @Enddate AND Holidays.Enddate >= @EndDate
                    OR Holidays.Startdate <= @Startdate AND Holidays.Enddate >= @Startdate
        END
    IF @Status <> 'AL'
        BEGIN
            SELECT  StartDate,
                    EndDate,
                    Duration,
                    [Status]
            FROM    Holidays
            WHERE   Holidays.Status = @Status
                    AND Holidays.Startdate <= @Startdate AND Holidays.Enddate >= @EndDate
                    OR Holidays.Startdate >= @Startdate AND Holidays.Enddate <= @EndDate 
                    OR Holidays.Startdate <= @Enddate AND Holidays.Enddate >= @EndDate
                    OR Holidays.Startdate <= @Startdate AND Holidays.Enddate >= @Startdate
        END
END
```

Comment: When combining ANDs and ORs, I personally do not want to remember which has the higher precendece. I always use brackets `( )` to make it really clear (to me or someone maintaining my code) what goes before what.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps the problem is incorrect priority in the second query. Please try using the following WHERE-clause in your second query:

```
WHERE   Holidays.Status = @Status
        AND (Holidays.Startdate <= @Startdate AND Holidays.Enddate >= @EndDate
        OR Holidays.Startdate >= @Startdate AND Holidays.Enddate <= @EndDate 
        OR Holidays.Startdate <= @Enddate AND Holidays.Enddate >= @EndDate
        OR Holidays.Startdate <= @Startdate AND Holidays.Enddate >= @Startdate)
```